# Will the regional flags on the tags be allowed on the new beta?

Tags: discussion

Previously in the Stack Exchange 1.0 version there were tags that contained flags for the regional type of questions.  Considering that our community came from various regions, it was really helpful for spotting questions that were specific to Canada, United States, United Kingdom, etc.  Will they return for the new beta?

Comment: +1 I agree, the flags were visually helpful to spot questions of interest (or vice-versa).  Questions *lacking* flags also stood out  more, as ones that could be answered irrespective of country.

Comment: +1 I want them back, but I think it's unlikely the team will re-add them while in beta.

Answer (score 5):

I hope so.  If nothing else they made me think an extra beat about any answer I glibly typed out.  That extra beat made me check my facts on a .gov website which could only lead to better answers.